# Using MIDI with a split keyboard

Tags: midi, keyboard

I can split the sound with a keyboard (in this case a Roland FP2), and that works fine. However, I woud like to be able to use two sound modules, MIDIed so that each module has reference to the notes from that split - say bass from the left and another sound from the right of the split.

It seems that whatever gets played is routed to both modules, with no splitting  - both sounds are activated from anywhere on the keyboard.

Is there a way in which to allow the split to work with the two modules? I doubt it'll be directly attributed to the keyboard, but how is it possible using MIDI? I need to use it *without* having a computer anywhere near!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First test would be to see if the data is channelised. I presume most people don't carry a midi analyser* these days [you can borrow my old one if you like;) but plugging it up to a DAW would tell you.

If it is, then set each slave module to receive on those alternate channels.

*I found an old article - 1986 - describing it… [Mu:Zines - Studiomaster MA36](http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/studiomaster-ma36/168). Mine still works, so it wasn't a bad investment ;)

From the [manual](http://www.cosmosmusic.com/upload/board/board_pds_manual/FP-2_e6.pdf), page 47…

> When the instrument is turned on, this is set to Channel “1.” The FP-2
> receives messages on all channels, 1–16.
>
> - When the keyboard is in dual play, the channel you’ve set here is transmitted.
> - When the keyboard is split into left and right sides, the transmission channel for messages from the left-hand side is fixed at
>   “3.”

Comment: Thanks, but not even sure the keyboard can send out discrete channels from the split. I guess it gets set to one out channel and that's it.

Comment: That's why I said to test it :P idk the Rolands, but iirc, Yamahas would always send split channels if you split the keyboard [It's been a long while since I did anything like this, so memory is more than a tad hazy]

Comment: I found the manual...

Comment: There's one for sale in UK - £175 - don't know if that's good or not. I like gear, but would i get any more moneysworth out of it at that price?

Comment: For one single use, not even worth the new price of 50 quid. I used to live with mine in my pocket. I used to do a very lot of midi stuff. These days, I have a DAW & tbh you don't need to do the faff with midi that you had to in the 80s/90s ;) I also still have my MJC-8 midi patch bay… last used 1995 I think. One day it will be a museum piece.

Comment: Found that little bit on p.47. Cheers. I just want to use it as said on the road, and thus don't want to take my computer out as well. When we finally manage to get out to gigs again. One day, maybe...

Comment: Just strapped it all together, and voila, it works! Brilliant, thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! Have fun at the next gig… whenever that may be ;)

Comment: Works fine with Nanobass and Nanopiano. Plug in Nanosynth, and channel change makes no difference, and split point changes. The plot thickens.

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested, on the Alesis Nanosynth (a great little module), there's a simple way to turn off any particular MIDI channels. That solves the problem, although it slightly changes the split point, by M3, so that's probably alterable from the motherboard.  If all else fails - READ THE INSTRUCTIONS!!